# Where is a template for messages in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, messages

For example I got this piece of html on catalog search result page

```
<p class="message notice">
    Your search '<strong>test</strong>' did not match any products.        <br>
    Showing results using some of your search terms        '<strong><strike>test</strike> 2 </strong>'.
</p>
```

Where this html was formed?

Answer (score 4):

There's no template for this code.

The HTML is generated dynamically by `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages` :

```
protected function _renderMessagesByType()
{
    $html = '';
    foreach ($this->getMessageTypes() as $type) {
        if ($messages = $this->getMessagesByType($type)) {
            if (!$html) {
                $html .= '<' . $this->firstLevelTagName . ' class="messages">';
            }

            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                $html .= '<' . $this->secondLevelTagName . ' class="message ' . 'message-' . $type . ' ' . $type .
                    '">';
                $html .= '<' . $this->contentWrapTagName . $this->getUiId('message', $type) . '>';
                $html .= $this->interpretationStrategy->interpret($message);
                $html .= '</' . $this->contentWrapTagName . '>';
                $html .= '</' . $this->secondLevelTagName . '>';
            }
        }
    }
    if ($html) {
        $html .= '</' . $this->firstLevelTagName . '>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Edit:

It seems like there's actually a template for it that generates the messages using the JS UI: `Magento\Theme\view\frontend\templates\messages.phtml` :

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                        "messages": {
                            "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>
```

If you want to change the template you can do the following in your layout XML:

```
<referenceBlock name="messages">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument xsi:type="string" name="template">Vendor_Module::messages.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: how to open data msg in pop up ?